# fadeToggle() not working

Tags: jquery

I has a strange error when using `fadeToggle()`

the jquery library inside the head section is: 
jquery-1.4.2.min.js

and this is the simple function:

```
 $(function(){
         $("#div1").click(function () {
                $("#div2").fadeToggle();
            });

            $("#div3").click(function () {
                $("#div4").fadeToggle();
            });
        });

  </script>
```

and this is the error from firebug

```
$("#div2").fadeToggle is not a function
```

I tried to change the jquery library to- jquery.js but then all the jquery plugin stop working and the error is the same

Any Idea what causing this

Thanks

Baaroz

Comment: have a look at my edited answer for a work around :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fadeToggle function is only available in jQuery 1.4.4 and above.

:)

Answer (score 1):

fadeToggle was added in 1.4.4
http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

so, that would be why,  try updating your jQuery version to the latest and it should be good to go!

ps:  make sure you read up on breaking changes before you upgrade, b/c there's been some pretty big changes from the early 1.4 ->1.5+

You can fake FadeToggle using animate:

```
$('#Div1').click(function(){

    if($('#Div2').css('opacity') == 1){

        $('#Div2').animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
    }
    else{
        $('#Div2').animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    }

});
```

have a look at my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/B73Sj/3/

Answer (score 0):

[fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) "version added: 1.4.4".

Answer (score 0):

[`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) was added on version 1.4.4 -- you won't be able to use it without updating your jQuery.

Comment: I tried https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js,but it stop all the pluging ,why?is it different library?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

> version added: 1.4.4

Update to the latest version, and try again :)