# Why is my jQuery toggle not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up a side menu and having some trouble with the jQuery Toggle. Everything else seems to function fine. I did try for a about 2 hours before posting here, so been getting a little frustrated (seeing how this is pretty basic stuff). Any suggestions?

Below is the format and exact order of my page layout, I only added separator text ("The side menu", "Image I click..", etc.) to make reading/understanding easier. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The side menu:

```
<div id="SideMenu" class="sidenav">
    <img class="CloseBtn" src="./wht_menu.png" />
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

Image I click to open the menu:

```
<img class="OpenBtn" src="./blk_menu.png" />
```

The rest of my page:

```
<div id="main">
My main page content goes here...
</div>
```

My CSS & jQuery:

```
<!--Slider Menu-->
<script>
$(".OpenBtn").click(function() {
$("#SideMenu").fadeToggle("fast", "swing");
});
</script>
<style>
#SideMenu{
width: 250px;
display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console.?

Comment: your toggle is working just fine, see here https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/zc1pvyy3/1/

Comment: What is your jQuery version? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372798/fadetoggle-not-working

Comment: got it working by adding this to the top :)

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the jQuery in this block ([docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".OpenBtn").click(function() {
    $("#SideMenu").fadeToggle("fast", "swing");
    });
});
```

**Working example using your code:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEaqqA

Comment: I tried this before posting, but TheDefinitionist is correct. I have another site where this exact function works. So I'm really getting confused here :(.. I see your example in codepen works great, not fair lmao.

Comment: Well, bu this exact code, I refer to the one I post in the OP:

$(".OpenBtn").click(function() {
$("#SideMenu").fadeToggle("fast", "swing");
});

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that jQuery not loaded on page at the time.

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".OpenBtn, .CloseBtn").click(function() {
            $("#SideMenu").fadeToggle("fast", "swing");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: I was missing the header link to jQuery

Comment: I was missing the jQuery header link. Qorking now as it was :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone! Although pivemi's answer was not the solution, a deeper review of his codepen link got things working, my doc wasn't calling on the jQuery library. Adding this to the top was my solution:

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS could look like this:

```
.menu {
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 272px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 999;
display: none;}
```

And your jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.show-menu').click(function(){
    fade_menu();
});
$('.menu-item').click(function(){
    fade_menu();
});});});

function fade_menu(){
        $('.menu').fadeToggle("fast");
}
```

Comment: Make sure you find a good looking way to make the menu items. And PLEASE, don't use png's to for your menu button

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question of "why is this code not working?".

Comment: Excuse me... @pivemi already explained why it's not working, so I thought, I could give him an example.

Comment: But you answered 2 minutes before pivemi ;)

Comment: Yeah, uhmmm... I wrote an example and then he answered and then I noticed that he already explained why it's not working and then I read the question again and he just asked why it's not working ^^